# Reading plist file from iOS project bundle

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a plist file customversion.plist which contains 2 properties max_ver (string) and min_ver (string) and are assigned the values 0 and 10 respectively.

Whenever XCode prepares the build, I want to read min_ver value and override Info.plist version using shell script.

I have written the following script:

```
CUSTOMVERPLIST = "customversion"
buildNumber=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print MAX_VER"
${BUILD_ROOT}/${CUSTOMVERPLIST.plist})
buildPlist=${INFOPLIST_FILE}
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $CONFIGURATION-$buildNumber" $buildPlist
```

My problem is that it seems that customversion.plist file is not being read and not getting the value of min_ver.

Can someone please suggest me about how to read the plist file from project bundle?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`${CUSTOMVERPLIST.plist}` is not a valid statement. This worked for me:

```
CUSTOMVERPLIST="${PROJECT_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}/customversion.plist"
buildNumber=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print MAX_VER" ${CUSTOMVERPLIST})
buildPlist="${INFOPLIST_FILE}"
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $CONFIGURATION-$buildNumber" $buildPlist
```

Comment: I copied and pasted your script. The result should be Debug-10 but it is not instead it is Debug-Usage: PlistBuddy [-cxh] <file.plist>
    -c <command> execute command, otherwise run in interactive mode
    -x output will be in the form of an xml plist where appropriate
    -h print the complete help info, with command guide

Comment: It seems that XCode has some problem. I deleted the whole projected and recreated new project. Ran your script again and now it worked. Thanks. Any idea on how to cleanup so that it always works?

Comment: Clean up what exactly?

Comment: I had my wrong script running..I replaced it with yours. It was still giving me result from my old script. So I thought that perhaps cleaning project would help but that did not work. So I deleted whole project and created new sample project and tested your script and it worked. So is there any place where script is cached and require cleanup?

Comment: If you modify the script, Clean (Cmd+Shift+K) the build and then Build to execute the script.